# Parsing JSON response by title - shows output

Tags: jquery, json, api, token

I have implemented the following post to the yotpo api (simple enough post request)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://yotpoapi.apiary.io/oauth/token');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (typeof cb !== "undefined") {
      cb(this);
    }
    else {
      alert(this.responseText);
    }
  }
};
xhr.send("{\n   \"client_id\": \"CLIENT ID\",\n   \"client_secret\": \"CLIENT SECRET KEY\",\n   \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\"\n}");
```

The response is the following (JSON format)

```
{
"access_token": "DUGKea0thVDL2muWzMAd7mYlkni46cJWhiX9tGTF"
"token_type": "bearer"
}
```

How can i get rid of everything but the access token response so it gives me the following: `DUGKea0thVDL2muWzMAd7mYlkni46cJWhiX9tGTF` in a variable.

Sorry i was posting the response in an alert format because i wanted to see in realtime what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response returned is JSON (which it appears to be) then you can obtain the value of `access_token` and store it in a variable like this:

```
var token = this.responseText.access_token;
```

If the response is a string, you can convert the JSON string to an object then obtain the desired property:

```
var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
response.access_token ; // DUGKea0thVDL2muWzMAd7mYlkni46cJWhiX9tGTF
```

Comment: I tried this as a test `this.responseText.access_token` and i keep getting `undefined` message.